# Passwordless ssh still asks for password when running as subprocess

Tags: ssh, python

I had setup passwordless ssh (keygen) to access my remote workspace from my personal laptop. On the remote server, I do use an account with a password to connect. Setting up public/private key authentication allowed me to connect without having to type this password.

The Python script I am running uses `subprocess.Popen()` to ssh into this remote workspace again. However, it is not a passwordless ssh during this. I have checked my permissions and have tried to delete and recreate the keys, yet this still happens.

Below is the relevant piece of Python code.

`subprocess.Popen(['ssh', machine_addr, 'cd ' + workspace + \
      '; python dispynode.py --serve 1 --clean --dest_path_prefix dispytmp_' + str(i)])`

Comment: What do you mean when you say _passwordless_? The account you are trying to log in is **really** passwordless? Are you using ip based authentication? Are you using public/private key authentication?

Comment: I have clarified what I meant by _passwordless_. I am using key authentication.

Comment: Is your key passphrase protected? Is the password ssh asks the remote host _password_ or the key _passphrase_?

Comment: Before I set up the keys, I used a password to access the server.

Comment: Are you using `ssh-agent` on the client to manage the SSH keys? If so, are you executing the Python script in an environment where the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is available? Are you executing your Python script as yourself or as another user?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been asked 4 years ago but I faced the same problem and found an explanation and a solution which worked for me, so this might be helpful for other people in the same situation.

**Context**

Same as you, I generated and shared the ssh keys between my client (Raspberry Pi) and my server. I was able to connect via ssh with no password prompt running `ssh user@server`.
But when my Python script tried to connect with `subprocess.Popen`, it asked for a password.

**Explanation**

The thing is I run my Python script with sudo because for some reasons I need to.

So the ssh command ran by `subprocess.Popen` used as ssh key the one located at `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`, while the one generated and shared with the server was located at `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`.

**Solution**

Add as argument to the ssh command the correct identification file :

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@server
```

So the Python line you need is the following :

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-i', '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa', 'user@server']
```

To which you add the commands you want (cd, mkdir, etc).

Hope this helps !